# Observable, access the input from the list

Tags: java, observable, rx-java

New to rx java.

I've a code like this, where I have a list of events, I need to perform an operation and then match the response to the event called.

I am getting a compilation error on line:
`.subscribe(value -> matchResponse(event, value));`

Ofcourse it makes sense, the event is not known at this point, is there a way for me to access the event that was passed on to the performOperation function so that I can execute my match response.

```
public void perforomObservableOperations(List<Event> events) {
Observable.from(events)
                        .flatMap(this::performOperation, 10)
                        .retry(10)
                        .toBlocking()
                        .subscribe(value -> matchResponse(event, value));
    }

private void matchResponse(Event event, Integer value) {
        eboxEvent.setValue(value);
    }


    private Observable<Integer> performOperation(Event event) {
        if (event == null) {
            return Observable.empty();
        }
        return xyz.getValue(event).toObservable();
    }
```

If there's a better way of doing this, I'm keen to know. Essentially using rxjava to help me retry, the `xyz` is a hystrix object to enable me to turn on circuit breaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a simple class to store `event` and `value`:

```
class Store {
    Event event;
    Integer value;

    Store(Event event, Integer value) {
        this.event = event;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

you can also use `Pair`, `Map.Entry` or something like that instead. Then you have to change `performOperation` and `matchResponse` in an appropriate way:

```
private void matchResponse(Store store) {

}

private Observable<Store> performOperation(Event event) {
    if (event == null) {
        return Observable.empty();
    }
    return xyz.getValue(event).toObservable().map((value) -> new Store(event, value));
}
```

Comment: Essentially, it's something similar what I went with. Since I was new to rxjava, was trying to see if I can get the event that goes to `performOperation()` in `subscribe()` as well.